# How can we create test record for "WebStoreNetwork" object in test class?-

Tags: salesforce, b2b

I need to create record of WebStoreNetwork in my test class.

```
SELECT WebStoreId
          FROM WebStoreNetwork
          WHERE NetworkId = :communityId
          WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
```

This is the query which is not getting covered in my test class. I am getting value in communityId variable in test class. Facing error "List has no rows to assignment".
Does anyone have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you post to [Salesforce StackExchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/).

But a direct answer is that as of Dec-2022 is not possible.

As of the next release, it should be: see [Spring'23 release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_comm_change_webstore_site_association.htm&type=5&release=242&language=en_US).